# Is the "classpath:" prefix specific to Spring, or is this a JVM concept?

Tags: java, spring, classpath

I have this in my web.xml:

```
<context-param>
     <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
     <param-value>classpath:spring-config.xml</param-value>
</context-param>
```

I suspect this is a convention used only by Spring? If it is, will it take my app longer to load, since I'm not specifying a direct file location, but now it must search the entire classpath?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> I suspect this is a convention used
>   only by Spring?

Yes, it stands for a [`ClassPathResource`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/resources.html#resources-implementations-classpathresource) and is part of [Spring's `Resource` abstraction](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/resources.html)

> If it is, will it take my app longer
>   to load, since I'm not specifying a
>   direct file location, but now it must
>   search the entire classpath?

No, a) it uses the ClassLoader internally which should be fast enough. b) you don't really have much of a choice. using files is a very bad idea in a webapp context, because it makes you dependent on implementation details that should be left to the implementing App server (a WAR may or may not be unpacked).

Comment: Thanks for the additional details!